# How to measure the memory usage for a small part of your code in Julia?

Tags: memory-management, julia

I would like to know, how can I measure the memory usage by a small part of my code? Lets say I have 50 lines of code, where I take only three lines (randomly) and find the memory being used by them.

In python, one can use such syntax to measure the usage:

```py
**code**

psutil.virtual_memory().total -psutil.virtual_memory().available)/1048/1048/1048 

**code**

psutil.virtual_memory().total -psutil.virtual_memory().available)/1048/1048/1048 

**code**
```

I have tried using `begin - end` loop but firstly, I am not sure whether it is good approach and secondly, may i know how can i extract just the memory usage using `benchmarktools` package.

Julia:

```
using BenchmarkTools

**code**

@btime begin
   ** code **
end

**code**
```

How may I extract the information in such a manner?

Look forward to the suggestions!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess one workaround would be to put the code you want to benchmark into a function and benchmark that function:

```
using BenchmarkTools

# code before

f() = # code to benchmark
@btime f() ;

# code after
```

To save your benchmarks you probably need to use `@benchmark` instead of `@btime`, as in, e.g.:

```
julia> t = @benchmark x = [sin(3.0)]
BenchmarkTools.Trial:
  memory estimate:  96 bytes
  allocs estimate:  1
  --------------
  minimum time:     26.594 ns (0.00% GC)
  median time:      29.141 ns (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        33.709 ns (5.34% GC)
  maximum time:     1.709 μs (97.96% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     992

julia> t.allocs
1

julia> t.memory
96

julia> t.times
10000-element Vector{Float64}:
   26.59375
   26.616935483870968
   26.617943548387096
   26.66532258064516
   26.691532258064516
    ⋮
 1032.6875
 1043.6219758064517
 1242.3336693548388
 1708.797379032258
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This is something I want to try only for few lines of the code, I think I can try to wrap it in a function. But I was thinking if there is something which can be implemented directly. 
And another thing, how can store the `time` as a variable and what is the method to extract just the memory usage?

Comment: Edited my answer with a potential solution